# Java: Identify the process using pid on jboss app server

Tags: java, jboss5.x

I have a shared environment where there are 3 VMs with 2 jboss-as 5 instances on each of them ( total 6 instances). On these instances, we have more that 15 applications deployed and all of them are java based. Lately we are getting a high CPU on one of the VMs, and when we do a 'top' on the Vm, it gives the list of all processes with java being the one having high CPU utilization %. But as I mentioned, this VM has more than 15 java applications, we dont know which application is consuming the high CPU cycles.

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Can someone please help on this?

Answer (score 1):

The PID will only give the JBoss server that the bad application is running on.
If you want to know which application is causing the problem, I recommend installing jprofiler or some other profiling tool.

Comment: If I restart jboss instance in profiling mode, the process taking long time will be killed, and I wont be getting the details. Since this process is happening intermittently, so is there any other way we can know the process just by PID, without stopping the instance.